# "Unable to create Directory" on wordpress running on XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, xampp

In these days i am experiencing an annoying error. I am trying to add plugins and themes on my wordpress site, which is handled by XAMPP running APACHE webserver and obviously MySql database. Everytime that i try to install a plugin (woocommerce in this case) i get the output below:
[image: Error Output]

So I tried to change permissions on all the wordpress directories (I am on windows 10), but that has not solved the issue yet. I find it pretty strange.

Actually woocommerce folders are stored anyway in the File System:

[image: File System]

I am not able to use the plugin from the site, anyway. I definitely need someone's help.

Comment: All plugins are installed in ```/wp-content/plugins``` - check what plugins are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to change folder permission and follow the below step:

- Change folder permissions on the wp-content directory to 775 and try to upload it again.
- If it fails, change the permissions to 777 and try to upload it again.
- If it still fails then do steps 1 and 2 for the “wp-content/uploads” directory too and try to upload it again.